# Checking function equality in a F# unit test

Tags: unit-testing, f#, nunit

I have a bunch of F# functions that implement different algorithms for the same input, kind of like the Strategy pattern. To pick the right strategy, I want to pattern match on the input argument and return the function as a value :

```
let equalStrategy points : seq<double> =
    ...

let multiplyStrategy factor (points: seq<double>) =
    ...

let getStrategy relationship = 
    match relationship with
        | "="  ->  equalStrategy
        | "*5" ->  multiplyStrategy 5.0
        | _    -> raise (new System.NotImplementedException(" relationship not handled"))
```

Now I want to write some unit tests to make sure that I return the right strategy, so I tried something like this in nUnit :

```
    [<TestCase("=")>]
    [<Test>]
    member self.getEqualstrategy( relationship:string ) =            
        let strategy = getStrategy relationship

        Assert.AreEqual( strategy, equalStrategy )
```

Now I think the code is correct and will do what I want, but the assertion fails because functions don't seem to have an equality operation defined on them. so my questions are :

(a) is there a way to compare 2 functions to see if they are the same, i.e. let isFoo bar = foo == bar, that I can use in an nUnit assertion?

or

(b) is there another unit testing framework that will do this assertion for me in F#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Testing whether an F# function returned by your `getStrategy` is the same function as one of the funcions you defined is also essentially impossible.

**To give some details** - the F# compiler generates a class that inherits from `FSharpFunc` when you return a function as a value. More importantly, it generates a *new* class each time you create a function value, so you cannot compare the types of the classes.

The structure of the generated classes is something like this:

```
class getStrategy@7 : FSharpFunc<IEnumerable<double>, IEnumerable<double>> {
  public override IEnumerable<double> Invoke(IEnumerable<double> points) {
    // Calls the function that you're returning from 'getStrategy'
    return Test.equalStrategy(points);
  }
}

// Later - in the body of 'getStrategy':
return new getStrategy@7(); // Returns a new instance of the single-purpose class
```

In principle, you could use Reflection to look inside the `Invoke` method and find which function is called from there, but that's not going to be a reliable solution.

**In practice** - I think you should probably use some other simpler test to check whether the `getStrategy` function returned the right algorithm. If you run the returned strategy on a couple of sample inputs, that should be enough to verify that the returned algorithm is the right one and you won't be relying on implementation details (such as whether the `getStrategy` function just returns a named function or whether it returns a new lambda function with the same behaviour.

Alternatively, you could wrap functions in `Func<_, _>` delegates and use the same approach that would work in C#. However, I think that checking whether `getStrategy` returns a particular reference is a too detailed test that just restricts your implementation.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for that. Interesting that if I call my getStrategy from a C# unit test with a Func type I can get this test to work. Appreciate the detailed response, thanks.

Comment: You can create a delegate value by writing `let foo = System.Func<_, _>(fun a -> a + a)` and then `foo = foo` returns `true`. To adapt the `getStrategy`, you'd have to return a delegate _instance_ and then compare it with the same delegate _instance_ (so creating a new delegate that points to the same function won't work). If you got that working in C#, can you post an example?

Comment: @Aidan What was your solution to this? Did you get your test working in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Functions doesn't have equality comparer:

You will have error: *The type '('a -> 'a)' does not support the 'equality' constraint because it is a function type*

There is a good post [here](http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/None/59265)

Comment: Sorry, I should have said in my question that this was the error I was getting. My assertion fails because functions don't have an equality comparer - I am asking if there is a way to get round tis.

Comment: Better would be to compare result of an equation *equalStrategy ([5.1] |> Seq.ofList())* function, or make you own custom comparer with comparison through reflection

Answer (score 2):

It would be very difficult for the F# compiler to prove formally that two functions always have the same output (given the same input). If that was possible, you could use F# to prove mathematical theorems quite trivially.

As the next best thing, for pure functions, you can verify that two functions have the same output for a large enough sample of different inputs. Tools like [fscheck](http://fscheck.codeplex.com/) can help you automate this type of test. I have not used it, but I've used scalacheck that is based on the same idea (both are ports from Haskell's QuickCheck)

Comment: Sorry, I am being unclear. I am not checking that two different functions give the same output, I am trying to check that the function returned by my pattern match is the function I want, given the input to the pattern match. So, in C# I could check if two Func<...> objects were the same, I am looking for an equivalent in F#.